# Возможно ли преобразование из файла .aap (Android App Bundle) в исходный (редактируемый) код?

Tags: android

Интересует существует ли техническая возможность (у простых смертных программистов), для извлечения исходного кода из файла .aap

Если предоставить доступ к Console Google аккаунту какому-нибудь пользователю, сможет ли он скачав Android App Bundle получить доступ к исходному коду?

Comment: В очень ограниченном смысле - да, сможет. НО это имеет смысл только в плане, например, поиска уязвимостей приложения. Скопировать таким образом приложение и выложить куда-нибудь в маркет не выйдет, как и существенно изменить. Точнее, выйдет, но с нуля написать проще.

Comment: Бандл не содержит исходных кодов и восстановить их в полной мере и с вашими комментариями невозможно. Но он содержит информацию для расшифровки стектрейсов, что здорово упростит реверс-инжиниринг, так как позволит вернуть оригинальные имена классов, полей и методов.